# Changing database compatibility level to 2008 and back to 2016 improves performance - how can it be?

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, database-performance, compatibility-level

Our customer reported an interesting phenomena that I can't explain: after they change database compatibility level from 2016 to 2008, and then back to 2016 the performance of a function that is used from a stored procedure significantly improves - from 9 seconds to 4. They don't execute the procedure with 2008 compatibility, only reset the compatibility.

I executed the procedure a couple of times, then flipped the compatibility, and executed the same procedure with the same parameters again - and it was using the same plan, but completed much faster. What can be the reason?
Here is the query that I used to compare performance and its plan.

[Query plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JA0FC.png)

Comment: Got an update from the customer - when they perform update statistics maintenance job followed by creating a full backup they see the performance degradation next morning that can be fixed by flipping the compatibility level. But if the backup runs prior to updating statistics, there are no performance problems.
My guess is that something is wrong with memory management and some portion of it becomes unavailable after "update statistics then backup" sequence and it gets cleared out by changing compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is some newer feature that is affecting this old stored procedure. Since you are not showing the code, it's hard to pinpoint the source of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mauricio! The stored procedure is quite complex, but one query that I use to track the performance change is very simple and creates very simple plan that uses index seek from a non-clustered index. So the question remains - why flipping compatibility level changes time that takes to perform the same operation? And it happens after some nightly job (possibly update statistics) is executed.

Answer (score 0):

When we change a compatibility level of a database, it will cause to remove the cached stored procedure plan. For example, when we execute the following stored procedure in the Adventureworks database, it will insert it into the plan cache.

```
   EXEC uspGetEmployeeManagers 96
```

[image]

And then we will change the compatibility of the database and this operation will remove the cached stored procedure plan.

```
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2017 SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL= 100
```

[image]

As a result after changing the compatibility level of a database, the stored procedure will use a fresh query plan. Using a freshly stored procedure query plan may improve query performance.

Comment: It's interesting that the same plan id is used before and after flipping the compatibility level even though it's removed from the cache.

Comment: Those are different tables. The Query Store feature writes information into the sys.query_store_plan table and you can check the count_compiles column in this table.